# n choose 2 for maximum possible number of inversions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I was watching this [Algorithms Course and section](https://youtu.be/7_AJfusC6UQ?t=412) where he mentions **n choose 2**. I wrote out the maximum number of inversions by hand for a 6-array element like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688836/maximum-number-of-distinct-inversions-in-an-array#answer-28688956).

However, I am curious how he got **n choose 2**. I don't see how combinations come from there. My best idea to get the formula would have been start with 1 and do an arithmetic series up to n-1 as the general formula but I don't see how he got **n choose 2**.

I get that for the maximum number of inversions the array has to be ordered in reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the array has to be ordered in reverse, no? So the first element is the biggest one, that gives you $n-1$ elements in inversion with it. Then the second one has $n-2$ elements in inversion with it. In general then the inversions are
$$\sum _{i=1}^n n-i=\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}i=\frac{(n-1)\cdot n}{2}=\binom{n}{2}.$$
Another way to think about this is that any pair of **different** elements in the array are in inversion! And so there are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose two elements in the array.

**Edit:** In general $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to pick $k$ objects *without order* out of $n$ objects. In your particular problem say you pick one number first, you have $n$ ways to do this. Then you want to pick a different number so now you have $n-1$ options, then you have $n\cdot (n-1)$ ways to do this by the multiplication principle. The problem is that you are giving them an order (for example, you could have chosen $3,2$ or $2,3$) so every pair of numbers you are picking **twice** so divide by $2$ to get $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\binom{n}{2}.$ The same principle can be extended to $\binom{n}{k}.$

Comment: I get the reverse order. I added that in the comments.

Comment: Could you expand on your last 2 sentences? I haven't seen combinations explained that way before. I get that they have to be different elements but how does the formula not pick the same number twice?

Comment: @heretoinfinity I edited to explain that.